# Delete HTML code from log file in SHELL

Tags: bash, sed, awk, grep

I have a log file containing html code i need to delete all the content between html tags for every possible match in this file. How is that possible using filters?

Example of my file:

```
some text here
<html>
code
</html>
some text there
<html>
code
</html>
some other text
```

The output should be:

```
some text here
some text there
some other text
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `awk` should do:

```
awk '/<html>/{f=1;next} !f; /<\/html>/{f=0}' file
some text here
some text there
some other text
```

Answer (score 1):

why not just:

```
sed '/<html>/,/<\/html>/d'
```

it works for your example.